# How do I dynamically fill a textfield with #ajax?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

As the title states, I'm wondering how I dynamically fill a textfield using an AJAX callback from a "select" form field.

I'm trying to test a select form with a number of options that, when changed, populates the textfield with data. I've tried setting the textfield's "`#default_value`", but it doesn't seem to work. Setting "`#value`" does work and I do get the information to show up in the textfield but this presents another problem. When I try to go to the next step and have a button save the data, the textfield's value remains what I set it to and doesn't change. What I mean is that when I select an option in the select form, the textfield gets populated correctly but if I change the textfield and hit save, the `$form_state` value is still what I set it to not what I changed it to. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

```
$form['profiles'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Profiles',
    '#options' => $profiles,
    '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'profile_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'profile-wrapper'
    )
);

$profile = isset($form_state['values']['profiles']) ? 
             _get_profile_info($form_state['values']['profiles']) : NULL;

$form['profile_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="profile-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#title' => 'Profile Name',
    '#value' => $profile == NULL ? '' : $profile[0]->{'name'}
);

$form['profile_save'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save Profile'),
    '#submit' => array(
        'save_profile'
    )
);
```

I'm saving the value of my textfield from the `$form_state` into a file for testing right now.

```
function save_profile($form, &$form_state){
    $fh = fopen('C:\out.txt', 'w+');
    fwrite($fh, $form_state['values']['profile_name']);
}

function profile_callback($form, &$form_state){
    return $form['profile_name'];
}
```

Comment: it seems like you left out the most important part of your code for us to help you debug. What does the profile_callback look like?

Comment: Sorry thought I included it, it just returns $form['profile_name'].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After messing with this for a while, I discovered that I needed to unset the textfield. Once I did this default_value started to work with ajax, below is the final code I had.

```
unset($form_state['input']['profile_name']);

$form['profiles'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Profiles',
    '#options' => $profiles,
    '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'profile_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'profile-wrapper',
    ),
);

$profile = isset($form_state['values']['profiles']) ? _get_profile_info($form_state['values']['profiles']) : NULL;

$form['profile_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="profile-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#title' => 'Profile Name',
    '#default_value' => $profile == NULL ? '' : $profile[0]->{'name'},
);
```

Comment: I'm trying to same thing on node-add form for specific content type, it does not seems working

Answer (score 2):

@Sathariel
I don't think you need to do `unset($form_state['input']['profile_name']);`

This is what I'd do to make it work, since it works for me:

```
$form['profiles'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Profiles',
    '#options' => $profiles,
    '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'profile_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'profile-wrapper',
        'event' => 'change',
    ),
);

$form['profile_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="profile-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#title' => 'Profile Name',
);

function profile_callback($form, &$form_state){
    $form['profile_name']['#value'] = _get_profile_info($form['profiles']['#values']);
    return $form['profile_name'];
}
```